# How to convert vendor-specific CSS

Tags: css

I have a CSS file that has all `-moz-css-property`throughout. What is the most efficient way to convert this file to one that also addresses Chrome, Safari, etc.? I'm hoping for a simple webapp that can do some magic.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure someone can get all fancy on this, but I'd just do some ctrl+f action on it.

If you've got a lot of repeating the same css values, this may be a good opportunity to optimize your code.

So...

```
.foo {
  color: red;
}

.bar {
  color: red;
}
```

could become...

```
.foo, .bar {
  color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will probably do 75% of what you want:

```
sed 's/\(.*\)-moz-\(.*\)/\1-webkit-\2\
\1-moz-\2\
\1-o-\2\
\1\2/1' test.css
```

Of course, IE will explode if you look at it funny.

Comment: I started by writing a quick script to do something just like this. The problem is properties like: border-bottom-right-radius which becomes -moz-border-radius-bottomright. They don't play nice. Grr.

Comment: Yeah, that's why it won't do 100% of what you want it to do. :-)